# W3C Validation: Strange HTML 5 errors

Tags: html, tags, w3c, validation

I get following errors when I validate following HTML5 Code:

```
<article>
 <header>
  <num>1</num>
  <hgroup>
   <h2><a href="#">Title with link</a></h2>
   <address>Teststreet 11</address>
  </hgroup>
 </header>
 <footer>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">&raquo; Mehr</a></li>
 </ul>
 </footer>
</article>
```

Errors:

- Element num not allowed as child of element header in this context.
- Element address not allowed as child of element hgroup in thiscontext.
- Element rating not allowed as child of element hgroup in this context.

Comment: Have you supplied a valid HTML 5 doctype? This will let the validator know that you're document is written using HTML 5. Otherwise, that element doesn't exist in older versions of HTML. 

e.g. 

<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Yes, it have the HTML5 Doctype

Comment: Afaik there's no such thing as a `num` or `rating` element.

Comment: It is not possible in HTML5 to create new elements?

Comment: @htw - Short answer - No it isn't. Long answer. You'd need to create an HTML5 extension specification defining the new elements and get it accepted as a standard by the W3C.

Comment: Then I will create an HTML 5 extension speficiation :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a tag called `num`

hgroup should only contain `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`

The errors are pretty self explanatory

> Element address not allowed as child of element hgroup in this context

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use an input element with type number:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Quantity (between 1 and 5): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: ps. Also, make sure you're nesting it within a form element!